# Are there RTMFP tutorial for P2P video streaming?

Tags: flash, streaming, video-streaming, webcam, red5

Are there RTMFP tutorial for P2P video streaming ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, although I don't see how red5 is involved.

you'll find all resources on the [adobe stratus](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/stratus/) project page. the [sample application](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/stratus/samples/#resources) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, as of this day red5 does not have support for RTMFP; but someday it will.